# Custom Fonts for webview to use

Tags: android, html, css, fonts, webview

Hello all I have an app that opens a webview containing articles that have combinations of text and images. As you know articles have varying fonts and I was wondering if there was a way for me to have several Helvetica fonts to be rendered by the web view exactly as it would be on a computer with those fonts installed; add them to my project in a way? thanks in advanced.

some sample html I'm using

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CONTENT-TYPE" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <TITLE>fin SUB_ The Lego Movie - Trent Erickson.docx</TITLE>
    <META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="LibreOffice 4.1.5.3 (Linux)">
    <META NAME="CREATED" CONTENT="0;0">
    <META NAME="CHANGED" CONTENT="20140330;153648463119746">
    <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
    <!--
        @page { margin: 1in }
        P { margin-bottom: 0.08in }
        A:link { so-language: zxx }
    -->
    </STYLE>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

</HEAD>
<BODY LANG="en-US" BGCOLOR="#ffffff" DIR="LTR">
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in; page-break-inside: auto; widows: 0; orphans: 0; page-break-after: auto">
<FONT COLOR="#ff3333"><FONT FACE="Helvetica LT Std Cond"><FONT SIZE=2>Arts
&amp; Culture</FONT></FONT></FONT></P>
<P STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in; widows: 0; orphans: 0">“<FONT FACE="HelveticaNeueLT Std Thin"><FONT SIZE=4 STYLE="font-size: 16pt">The
Lego Movie” Lego Sets: Lego Misunderstood Their Own Movie</FONT></FONT>
                  <img src="lego.jpg">
</P>
<P ALIGN=RIGHT STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in; page-break-inside: auto; widows: 0; orphans: 0; page-break-after: auto">
<FONT FACE="Helvetica LT Std Cond">By:
</FONT><FONT FACE="Helvetica LT Std Cond">Trent Erickson                                                             
</FONT><FONT FACE="Helvetica LT Std Cond">Issue 3</FONT></P>

<P ALIGN=RIGHT STYLE="margin-bottom: 0in; widows: 0; orphans: 0">
</P>
<P STYLE="text-indent: 0.5in; margin-bottom: 0in; page-break-inside: auto; widows: 0; orphans: 0; page-break-after: auto">
<FONT FACE="HelveticaNeueLT Std">With over 4 billion dollars of
revenue, Lego is one of the most successful names in the toy
business, and rightly so: Lego is fantastic. It’s gender neutral,
it’s for kids, and it’s for adults. You can make a plane, a
train, or an automobile. Lego can be whatever you want it to be, but
it can also be constructed to perfectly match the instructions on the
cover of the set. </FONT>
</P>
```

my style sheet

```
 html {
    background-color: #e6e9e9;
    background-image: linear-gradient(270deg,rgb(230,233,233) 0%,rgb(216,221,221) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270deg,rgb(230,233,233) 0%,rgb(216,221,221) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg,rgb(230,233,233) 0%,rgb(216,221,221) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgb(230,233,233) 0%,rgb(216,221,221) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(270deg,rgb(230,233,233) 0%,rgb(216,221,221) 100%);
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em 2em 2em;
    max-width: 800px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
   font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #545454;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}


img {
    background: transparent;

    display: block;
    margin: 1.3em auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
}

@keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}
```

and the coed for my webview

```
public class Article extends Activity{
    private WebView webview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.articleview);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String KEY_LINK = b.getString("b");
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

                webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);



        webview.loadUrl(url);

        webview.loadUrl(KEY_LINK);



    }


}
```

Comment: You might want to look into the latest HTML standards (you are using a few things that are now depreciated).

Comment: a lot of that is due to a conversion script to convert them from docx to html. just be too time cunsuming to do each one manually. but thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [buy the Helvetica Webfont](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/) for use in your projects. Then you only have to include the css link provided to you and the text will be rendered in Helvetica in every remotely modern browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've already purchased the whole helvetica family and was wondering if i could just reference the tff an the otf from my project?

Comment: While you could convert them to a webfont and serve them together with the webpage, this would be a violation of the license - as I understand, you only have the print license.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely your helvetica purchase includes the right to use in a webapp. In fact the terms of use of fonts like Helvetica are designed to segment the market and make you pay each time you find a new use for the fonts. Therefore it is your choice: either Helvetica is worth the money for your need, or you'd better served by a free and open font (like those on the Google font service) with few limitations on the way you can use them. (and the fonts are not necessary worse, they just don't have the recognition of old fonts like Helvetica).

Comment: I suggest [OpenSans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) as a worthy and free Helvetica alternative.